# How to add listener for Reactjs cookies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, listener

I'm setting a React cookie in 1 component (Menu.js) and trying to listen for it in another component (Home.js)

Currently using universal-cookie: https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie and there is an addChangeListener function. However, I can't seem to get it working, this code snippet in Home.js simply doesn't trigger an update when I set the cookie in Menu.js.

```
const cookies = new Cookies();

cookies.addChangeListener(onCookieChange);

function onCookieChange() {
  console.log("Noticed cookie change!")
}
```

Tried binding onCookieChange like this according to other stackoverflow answers:

```
cookies.addChangeListener(this.onCookieChange.bind(this));
```

and got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'onCookieChange' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late here but here's how can you listen for cookie changed with a simple useEffect hook. When **MyComponent** is mounted it adds the listener, and when **MyComponent** is unmounted the listener is removed.

```
const cookies = new Cookies();

const MyComponent = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const cookieChangeListener = (name, value) => {
      console.log('The cookie ', name, ' changed to ', value)
    }

    cookies.addChangeListener(cookieChangeListener);

    return () => {
      cookies.removeChangeListener(cookieChangeListener);
    }
  },[]);
  
  ...
}
```